# React native- How to share data in my components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, mobile, react-context

I am trying to access user data that is saved on my mobile device through out all components using useContext but I am getting nothing
here is the context provider:

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";
import { getAllData, save } from "../utilities/store";
import { UserStruct } from "../constants/UserStruct";


const UserContext = createContext();
const UserUpdate = createContext();
function UserProvider ({ children }) {

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(UserStruct);

  const logOut = () => {
    //alert if ok then clear all data
    Alert.alert(
      "Log Out",
      "Are you sure you want to log out?",  
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
          style: "cancel"
        },
        { text: "Log out", onPress: () => {
          clearAllUserData();
        }}
      ]);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getValueFor('LoggedIn').then((value) => {
        if (value === 'true') {
            getAllData().then((value) => {
                setUserData(value);
                console.log("UserData: ", value);
            })

        }
    })
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={ userData }>
        <UserUpdate.Provider value={{ logOut }}>
         {children}
        </UserUpdate.Provider>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function useUserContext() {
  return useContext(UserContext);
}

export function useUserUpdate() {
    return useContext(UserUpdate);
}

export default UserProvider;
```

Here is My APP:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <ApplicationProvider {...eva} theme={eva.light}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <AppNavigator />
          </NavigationContainer>
      </ApplicationProvider>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}
```

when I try to access the userData using the follwoing code:

```
  const userData = useUserContext();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(userData); 
  }, [userData]);
```

it prints the default values for userData
I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Isnt the useUserContext suppose to be getting the current userData and update it is the state changes. Where am I going wrong? thank you for the help.

Comment: Where do you use this `const userData = useUserContext();`?

Comment: in the Homescreen component in APP. Component is large that is why I didn't paste it here.